# Use of undefined constant caused by dash?

Tags: php, simplexml

This works

```
$source = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
foreach ($source->programme as $programme) {
  echo $programme->title . "<br />";
}
```

But this does not

```
$source = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
foreach ($source->programme as $programme) {
  echo $programme->sub-title . "<br />";
}
```

I get this error :

> "Notice: Use of undefined constant title - assumed 'title' in ..."

This error is likely caused by the use of "-" in second code snippet.

My question is: Can I escape the dash character and make this work?

Comment: it's actually a "minus" sign, according to PHP syntax

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow this way:

```
$programme->{'sub-title'}
```

This trick is even described in [basic simplexml usage](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) section